# Adjust component size for MUI2

Tags: nsis

Actually I´m trying to change my component size of the MUI2 Components of the following pages:
`!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE
 !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
 !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
 !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
 !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH`

I did add also the Customfunction to change the size of each window, with the nsResize Plug-In. Now i have the problem that the Components are missplaced and to small, in width and height.

I searched for it and did find some ideas for my question. But i do not want to use the resourcehacker to create the UI new, for several personal reasons. The i saw that i can use the System Plug-In to make the adjustments, but it´s overhelming me with the information Source.

Then I tried to execute it my self and failed.
My actual Solution is:

```
Function .myGuiInt
  System::Call "user32::GetClientRect(i #32770 , i r1)"
  System::Call "user32::SetWindowPos(i 1000, i, i, i 15000, i, i)"
  ....
FunctionEnd
```

I tried to change the size of the textbox where i set the license.
But i got no effect, how can i make this calls that i can effect the UI?

Comment: Why can't you use Resource Hacker? Do you only want to resize the components page or should all the pages have a larger size? You need to know Win32 programming to use the System plug-in...

Comment: I do not want manipulate it, because i will hold olny the standard lib and only extend it. That was my reason if my actual Solution is correct and i want some tips in that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution for the components page is to `!define` `MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_SMALLDESC` or `MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_NODESC`, this will make the components list larger.

If this is not large enough then the absolute best solution is to create your own UI. You will have to use Resource Hacker or some other .EXE editor to do this but it is a one time operation, you do not have to redistribute the editor, just the produced UI file along with your .NSI if other people also need to compile your installer. Take `...NSIS\Contrib\UIs\modern.exe` and edit it to suit your needs and then apply it with `MUI_UI` (or `ChangeUI` for classic installers).

The advantage of this is that you will be working with [dialog units](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlgbox/about-dialog-boxes#dialog-box-measurements), not pixels and there are also no programming skills required.

The final option is to do it at run time. This means that you will be working in pixels most of the time so you should not really hardcode any sizes. To use the System plug-in you have to be familiar with Win32 programming. Knowing C/C++ or some other low-level programming language also helps.

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_NODESC
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW fullsize_tweak_components_page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

!define /ifndef SWP_NOZORDER 4
!define /ifndef SWP_NOACTIVATE 0x10
Function fullsize_tweak_components_page
System::Call 'USER32::GetClientRect(p $mui.ComponentsPage, @ r0)' ; Get the size of the inner dialog
System::Call '*$0(i,i,i.r3,i.r4)' ; Extract the right and bottom members from RECT
System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(p $mui.ComponentsPage.Components, p 0, i 0, i 0, i $3, i $4, i ${SWP_NOZORDER}|${SWP_NOACTIVATE})' ; Resize the components list
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Your Solution helped me a lot to solve my problem, i used the win32 way to do it